# How to change Linux kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, source

I have downloaded and unzipped the Linux Kernel. What file(s) in kernel source file(s) are responsible for displaying Version string in uname ?
I want set version to 10, without dots 10.0.5

```
# uname -r
Linux 10
```

Answer (score 3):

It's described in the top level `Makefile`.

For example, [from here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile),

```
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 5
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION = -rc6
NAME = Blurry Fish Butt

# *DOCUMENTATION*
# To see a list of typical targets execute "make help"
# More info can be located in ./README
# Comments in this file are targeted only to the developer, do not
# expect to learn how to build the kernel reading this file.
```